# How to build a list of all git commits on master?

Tags: node.js, git, git-log

Given a git repository, I would like to list all of the commits on the branch `origin/master` by date along with their SHA values. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

My desired result is an array of objects in Node.js representing a git repository, containing commit data such as

```js
    [
      {
        date: "2020-02-02",
        sha: "03ffd2d7c3c1fdcc86f947537c6f3afa209948dd",
      },
      {
        date: "2019-03-13",
        sha: "3a7dbc7e6ab332ebbca9a45c75bd608ddaa1ef95",
      },
      ...
    ]
```

or simply a comma-separated list such as

```
2020-02-02
03ffd2d7c3c1fdcc86f947537c6f3afa209948dd
2019-03-13
3a7dbc7e6ab332ebbca9a45c75bd608ddaa1ef95
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would start with using what git provides out of the box. Here's an example:

```
git log origin/master --date-order --format=%H%n%cs
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned **node** here, I put together a solution for your question entirely working with node enviornment.

As far as I tested this might be limited to local repositories, but I'll do more tests later and let you know if it can be used for repositories from github too.

You need **gitlog** module for this. [gitlog npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitlog)

You can install it using `npm install gitlog` (more info in above mentioned page).

```
// You need gitlog module to get and parse the git commits
const gitlog = require("gitlog").default ;

// You can give additional field names in fields array below to get that information too.
//You can replace `__dirname` with path to your local repository.
const options = {
    repo : __dirname,
    fields : ["hash", "authorDate"]
}

const commits = gitlog(options) ;

//logObject takes one parameter which is an array returned by gitlog() function
const logObject = commits => {
    let log = [] ;
    commits.forEach( value => {
        const hash = value.hash ;
        const date = value.authorDate ;
        log.push({hash, date}) ;
    })
    return log ;
}

//This returns the results in an array 
logObject(commits) ;

//This returns the array in accending order
logObject(commits).sort((first, second) => {
    return Date.parse(first.date) - Date.parse(second.date) ;
}) ;


//This returns the array in decending order
logObject(commits).sort((first, second) => {
    return Date.parse(second.date) - Date.parse(first.date) ;
}) ;
```